# Which is the range of values coming out from a hdr environment texture node?

Tags: node-editor, light, hdri

Which is the range of values coming out from a hdr environment texture node?
Is it normalized 0.0 - 1.0 or something else?

Comment: HDR stands for High Dynamic Range, the idea behind it is to have values that can exceed the 0-1 range. There is no set limit for the values of HDR. When using images as environment, those images would need to be in a format tha can accommodate such values (like HDRi, preferably OpenEXR). Using PNG, JPEG or other formats will not limit you to a low dynamic range, but will give you values that are distorted by the baked in transform curves on the file.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I knew that, but when I choose a real HDR photo in the Environment texture node, his value output is normalized to 0-1 range or will it go above 1?

Comment: The output values are not normalized so they can exceed 1, normalizing or clipping would defeat the usefulness of HDR